# Changing scan order of Gibbs Sampler on each iteration

Tags: gibbs, dirichlet-process

I'm implementing an algorithm that requires the use of Gibbs Sampling and, due to the nature of the way I store the values, it would be efficient to change the order of the updates on each component at every iteration.

For example, if I have three components, the first iteration will be over [1, 2, 3], but the next one could be [2, 3, 1], then [1, 3, 2], and so on.

If the answer is "it depends" then I'll edit the question with more details.

Comment: The answer to which question? Changing the order at each iteration is legitimate, whether it is done randomly or deterministically.

Answer (score 3):

One can consider a Gibbs sampler as a combination of componentwise Markov kernels $G_i$ with $$G_i(\theta,\theta^\prime)=p(\theta^\prime_i|\theta_{-i})\delta_{\theta_{-i}}(\theta^\prime_{-i})$$Since each kernel is stationary wrt the joint distribution, so is the combination. The only major constraint is ensuring that the combination results in an irreducible Markov chain, meaning that all components must move infinitely often. Other than that, considering an arbitrary sequence $(i_n)_n$ over $\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$ leads to a valid Gibbs sampler
$$G_{i_m}\circ\cdots\circ G_{i_2}\circ G_{i_1}$$

Comment: I think the OP wants to change the scan order in *each iteration*. So the one-step kernel will not be time-homogeneous, right?. However, I think their three-step kernel (if they have 3 components) will be time-homogenous.

Comment: Changing the order at each iteration (or $p$th) is ok as well provided the order is not induced by earlier realisations of the chain.

Comment: Yes, ergodicity would still be guaranteed in that case, so things would be ok.